# How to strip and removed special characters from the out put of python sub process

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using Python sub process to execute command as shown below:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['debug', 'file.tgz'], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    print(str(output.strip()).encode())
    return_code = process.poll()

    if return_code is not None:
         break
```

What i am getting out put is shown below:

```
b"b'Registers:'"
```

And this is what i am expecting.

```
Registers:
```

I am using encode but still seeing same out put. If i run the same process on command line i am getting the same desired out put.

How can i remove these special characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Skip the str(); that'll get rid of the inner `b'...'`
- You want to .decode rather than .encode, because you want to turn a byte-stream (which came from the subprocess) into a string (for printing). You'll need to know which encoding it's using, and (if applicable) what to do with malformed data.
- (optional) Strip the whitespace after decoding, not before, to also strip non-ASCII whitespace characters (if any).

```py
    print(output.decode('utf8', errors='strict').strip())
```